# c# a collection to hold two arraylist

Tags: c#, collections, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I am using C#.

I've created 2 arraylists called `Names` and `Performances` and the data in them are filled from my database.

I wanna create an arraylist or something like an array of 2 dimensions so
`array[Name][Performance]`.

- `array[0][0]` => should give me first persons first performance data
- `array[0][1]` => should give me firstpersons second performance data
- `array[0][2]` => should give me first persons third performance data...

The size of `Names` and `Performance` are changeable due to diffrent sql queries.
since sizes are changeable i tried to use loops and size of `Name` and `Performance` arraylists in those loops. How can i handle that collection to hold both of my arraylists?

Comment: How do you associate Name and Performance?

Comment: Is the data for 'Names' and 'Performances' in the same DB? If so maybe you can create result set in SQL and convert to some custom type after retrieval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use a generic List ?

You can then for instance create a type which holds the Person and his performance data, like this:

```
class PersonPerformance
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public List<Performance> Performances { get; set; }
}
```

And you create a collection easily:

```
var performances = new List<PersonPerformance>();
```

Comment: Hey OP, Look into the Object-Oriented Programming concept of "Composition". This is what Frederik is talking about. This concept will open so many doors for you when dealing with your data. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that

```
        IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> innerList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        IList<IList<KeyValuePair<String,string>>> list=new List<IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();
        list.Add(innerList);
```

Where KeyValuePair contains Name and Perfomance element

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Names are of the type string.

I usually do (if I don't have set size)

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, TYPE_X>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, TYPE_X>>();
```

or (the size is known)

```
KeyValuePair<string, TYPE_X>[] array = new KeyValuePair<string, TYPE_X>[size];
```

or better

```
 public Dictionary<string, TYPE_X> dict = new Dictionary<string, TYPE>();
```

if names are unique and I want to acces them like that (not in order):

```
TYPE_X object = dict["myName"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Use `Dictionary<Name,List<Performance>>` Type 
hence for each name you get the set of Performances